# Most effective grid search with rfe

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's consider classification data:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes = 2, n_features = 5)
```

I want to grid search over my defined hyperparameters for 2, 3, and 4 number of features.

**My solution**

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid, StratifiedKFold
import numpy as np
param_grid = {'n_estimators': [50, 100, 150], 
              'learning_rate': [0.1, 1, 5], 
              'n_features': [30, 31, 32]}

cv_res=[]

cv = StratifiedKFold()
model = AdaBoostClassifier(random_state = 0)

for params in ParameterGrid(param_grid):

    cv_folds = []
    for train_index, val_index in cv.split(X, y):
        X_train, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
        Y_train, Y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]

        model = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators = params['n_estimators'], 
                                   learning_rate = params['learning_rate'],
                                   random_state=0)        
        rfe = RFE(estimator=model, n_features_to_select=params['n_features'], step=1)
        rfe.fit(X_train, Y_train)

        cv_folds.append(rfe.score(X_val, Y_val))

    cv_res.append(np.mean(cv_folds))
```

Do we hany any more efficient or elegant solution? I'm asking becuase this algorithm takes really a lot of time

Comment: Is it a possibility to use subprocesses ?

Comment: Have a look at [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), it uses `ParameterGrid` and performs a parallelized parameter search.